# Codesign failed on 10.12 Sierra

Tags: macos, codesign, macos-sierra

Just installed 10.12 and Xcode 8 `codesign` command fails even from terminal with `A cryptographic verification failure has occurred.` and no further details. Any solutions?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the command line tools from the Developer portal?

Comment: I did, no luck. Even reinstalled Xcode

Comment: I'm having the same problem on a new project.

Comment: @MaximeAubaret Good to know its not just isolated, I mean it sucks but you know. Please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Chinese website](http://www.jianshu.com/p/46c9de16a67a) helps me to solve that issue.

Launch "Keychain Access", go to "Preferences..." and click "Reset My Default Keychain". After that I was finally able to build my projects.

Comment: This worked for me too, combined with a full restart

Comment: This worked for me. At least until I copied my passwords back so that I could continue to use them, and then it started bombing out again. So somehow some password in my keychain must be causing it, but I haven't quite figured out which one yet.